# p-dropdown no muestra el item seleccionado

Tags: html, angular, primeng

estoy migrando mis "select" a "p-dropdown" para una mayor fluidez y consigo cargar la lista de items correctamente, pero a la hora de mostrar los datos guardados en BBDD no se me selecciona el item que le paso por ng-model.

Es decir, creo un nuevo Pedido, y para señalar el Municipio al que corresponde ese pedido hay un "p-dropdown" que carga los municipios correctamente.
relleno los datos (seleccionando el municipio etc) y lo guardo.
Luego, cuando entro al pedido, se cargan todos los datos correctamente excepto el Municipio, que  selecciona el primer elemento del dropdown en vez del que he seleccionado antes.

*En BBDD lo he comprobado y el municipio se guarda correctamente.*

**pedidos.ts**

*Ejemplo de como se cargan los datos para el pedido seleccionado "pedidoSeleccionado"*

```
{
  ...
  IdMunicipio: 5,
  MunicipioNombre: "Melilla",
  ...
}
```

**pedidos.html**

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="municipios" [(ngModel)]="pedidoSeleccionado.IdMunicipio" optionLabel="Nombre" (onChange)="cambioMunicipio($event.value);"></p-dropdown>
```

esto me funcionaba correctamente cuando lo aplicaba al select, pero aqui se me esta haciendo imposible...
¿Alguna sugerencia?

gracias de antemano

Comment: Te recomiendo ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295604/detectar-change-en-p-dropdown-en-angular-6-con-primeng-primefaces/295877?noredirect=1#comment541439_295877 talvés tengas algo similar a mi situación. saludos.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses los ReactiveForms de Angular y dejes de usar los [(ngModel)] ens los p-dropdowns. Te pondo un ejemplo de como lo deberias hacer y seguramente te funcione.

component.ts

```
public form: FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ municipio: [null, Validators.required] });
}
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <p-dropdown [options]="options" formControlName="municipio" optionLabel="name" (onChange)="changeMe(form.value.municipio.value);">
  </p-dropdown>
</form>
```