# Detectar change en (p-dropdown) en Angular 6 con "PrimeNG - PrimeFaces"

Tags: angular, angular6, dropdownlist, selectores

Antiguamente Tenía esta funcionalidad:

```
<div class="row">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3">Aplicación:</label>
     <div class="col-md-9" class="visorg500-select-filter">            
      <select [(ngModel)]="varApps">
        <option  *ngFor="let valorApp of listApps" [value]="valorApp.id">
         {{valorApp.label}}
        </option>
      </select>
     </div>
   </div>
```

del lado de **`typeScript`**:

```
private LoadApps(): void {
 this.listApps = [
   { id: 1, label: 'PREMIER' },
   { id: 2, label: 'G500 FLEET' }
 ];
 this.varApps = this.listApps[0].id;
}
```

lo cuál me seleccionaba y me permitía cachar en la "**varApps**" el id cuando se realizaba el cambio.

Por cuestiones de Diseño y de presentación implementé lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Aplicación:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
     <p-dropdown class="visorg500-select-filter" [options]="listApps" filter="true"
      [style]="{'width':'70%'}">
      <select [(ngModel)]="varApps">
        <option *ngFor="let valorApp of listApps" [value]="valorApp.id">
          {{valorApp.label}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </p-dropdown>
   </div>
 </div>
```

El punto es que ya no me permite, tomar el id producido por el evento del cambio.

Me supongo que por el uso de (**p-dropdown**), pero hasta ahora no he podido conseguir lo que busco.

Agradeceré si alguien pueda apoyarme, con alguna orientación, Saludos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deberías tener un p-dropdown **y** un select, el componente de primeNG debe reemplazar totalmente tu antiguo select, algo como

```
<p-dropdown class="visorg500-select-filter" [options]="listApps" filter="true"
  [style]="{'width':'70%'}" [(ngModel)]="varApps">
```

Comment: Trabajé eso al inicio guiado por la documentación del PrimeNG , pero no me permite obtener el id del Change en el VarApps, puesto que de allí tomo para validar de acuerdo a mi aplicación seleccionada con la *ngIf directiva, para mostrar o no cierta información.

Comment: Me ha sido útil, pero para usar las condiciones de mi comentario anterior debo acceder al id o label, ejemplo: *ngIf="varApps.id_app == 1 || *ngIf="varApps.label== "PREMIER"...... Eso era lo que me estaba faltando, Gracias Pablo.

Comment: Si te soy sincero, no he dado una respuesta más detallada porque siempre uso formularios reactivos, que simplifica mucho observarlos y detectar acciones sobre ellos y, por tanto, no conozco mucho cómo trabajar con ngmodel